# Converting style-encapsulated CSS to RTL in Angular

Tags: angular, rtlcss

We have a rather large project, with almost all of our CSS inside components. We need to generate RTL styles for the widget, and have attempted to use [postcss-rtl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-rtl). When we've attempted to do so, the `[dir]` attribute prefix that `postcss-rtl` adds is being suffixed with the `_ngcontent...` selector. We need to stop this so that the CSS applies to the html as expected.

```
// Current output
[dir][_ngcontent-c30] .total-deposit_value[_ngcontent-c30] {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

// Expected output
[dir] .total-deposit_value[_ngcontent-c30] {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

We're simple importing `postcss-rtl` into our webpack config, and calling it at the bottom of our `postcssImports()`.

I'm not entirely sure how else we can approach this, without turning setting `ViewEncapsulation.None`, which would cause CSS conflicts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

**Use `/deep/` in your selector**

Component styles normally apply only to the HTML in the component's own template.
Use the `/deep/` shadow-piercing descendant combinator to force a style down through the child component tree into all the child component views. The `/deep/` combinator works to any depth of nested components, and it applies to both the view children and content children of the component.

```
[dir] /deep/ .total-deposit_value {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't resolve my issue. `[dir]` is prepended using rtlcss, I'm not doing it manually. After the compilation process, Angular is adding the the scoped attributes. By adding `/deep/`, I would still end up `[_ngcontent-c30]` being added to `[dir]`. So I'd have `[dir][_ngcontent-c30] /deep/ .total-deposit_value[_ngcontent-c30] {...` instead.